# dialog activity hides under call screen when secure lock is on, android

Tags: android, dialog, popupwindow, lockscreen

Im doing app like truecaller, and want to implement popup activity over native callscreen. Its okay, but when device locked on pin guard activity shows, but instantly hide under callscreen. Here is my code:

```
public class IcomingCallActivity extends Activity {

    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp;
    private int scrennHeight;
    @Bind(R.id.phoneTextView) TextView phoneTextView;
    @Bind(R.id.nameTextView) TextView nameTextView;
    @Bind(R.id.avatarImageView) CircleImageView avatarImageView;
    @Bind(R.id.spamTextView) TextView spamTextView;
    @Bind(R.id.container) FrameLayout container;

    private ActivityManager mActivityManager;
    private boolean mDismissed = false;

    private static final int MSG_ID_CHECK_TOP_ACTIVITY = 1;
    private static final long DELAY_INTERVAL = 100;

    private String number;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming_call);


        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        scrennHeight = getDisplayHeight();
        initiallizeScreen();

        final View view = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.container);


        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        lp.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY();
                        wlp = getWindow().getAttributes();
                        wlp.y = lp.topMargin - scrennHeight / 2;
                        getWindow().setAttributes(wlp);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        SharedPreferencesSaver.get().saveCallDialogPosition((int) event.getRawY());
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
}
```

Style of activity is Dialog, but when i try to set it as fullscreen window has a black background and native callscreen dont visible